# Private vs Public Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript

can someone please explain what the difference is between these two functions?

```
(function(Engine, $, undefined) { //hidden from scope
    //public function below
    Engine.Init = function() {
        console.log("IM PUBLIC");
    }

    //anonymous functions below
    function Login() {
        console.log("IM PRIVATE");
    }
})( window.Engine = window.Engine || {}, jQuery );
```

Specifically, I'd like to know why `Engine.Init()` is available in the `Console` but `Login` isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Init` is a property of the `Engine` object that refers to a function.
You can access it like any other property.

`Login` is a local variable within the anonymous, "immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE); like other local variables, its name is only visible within the declaring function

Comment: One question I would like to ask you here though it might not be related to this question: what is the difference between (function(){}) versus function(){}? Does this has something to deal with anonymous function or scope or what is it?

Comment: It's just a syntactic embellishment to make sure the function definition is immediately callable. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/, under "An aside: functions, parens, and SyntaxErrors."

Comment: @lmjohns3: You pointed me to the absolutely right direction. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Lovely explanation and all the better for that link! Cheers guys!

Answer (score 2):

Engine is global because of the parameters:

```
(window.Engine = window.Engine || {}, jQuery)
```

and available in the global namespace, if you did:

```
Engine.Login = function(){}
```

That would be available globally.

The function Login is only available inside the scope of the anonymous self executing function.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a difference between the functions themselves. The only difference is that the first function is assigned to a property of an object (`Engine.init`) defined in **global** scope (`window.Engine`), whereas the second function is defined **locally** inside the [*immediately invoked function expression* (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Here is a equivalent, but simpler example:

```
function foo() {
    // 1
    window.globalFunc = function() {
        // global/public
    }

    // 2
    function localFunc() {
        // local/private
    }
}

foo();
```

Because the first function is *explicitly* assigned to a global variable, it can be accessed outside of `foo`, after `foo` was executed. `localFunc` is not exported and hence local to `foo`, i.e. it cannot be accessed and doesn't exist outside of `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

This thing

```
function(Engine, $, undefined) {
...
}
```

is actually a closure. So everything define inside that function is available only in that scope. When you do

```
Engine.Init = ...
```

You create a property which is attached to Engine object. In your case Engine is a global object, which means that you have an access to it via the console.

Comment: *"So everything define inside that function is available only in that scope."* That has nothing to do with closures, that's how *every* function works. Although technically every function is a closure in JS, the issue here has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: Hm ... every function in JavaScript (as every other thing) is an object. We could say that the properties of the object are public variables. If you add "var something = ..." inside the function that thing is a private variable available only for the closure's scope. Isn't that true?

Comment: You could say that, but it doesn't matter whether the function is a closure or not.