# javascript - Object has no methods?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, typeerror

So my problem is, I made a basic object in javascript with two methods, but when I call them chrome's debugger says they don't exist. But the problem is, if I call any of the methods inside the object they don't give any problems but outside the object I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<'player> has no method 'set'

(Note: the ' in player was added otherwise Stack Overflow would trim 'player')

Here is the code:

```
function player() {
    this.x=25; this.y=1;
    function set(setx,sety) {
        this.x = setx;
        this.y = sety;
        document.getElementById('x'+this.x+'y'+this.y).style.backgroundColor='000000';
    }
    function move(movex,movey) {
        document.getElementById('x'+this.x+'y'+this.y).style.backgroundColor='';
        set(movex,movey);
    }
}
```

that's in the header, here's the javascript code in the body:

```
var x = 25;
mainPlayer = new player();
mainPlayer.set(x,1);
var interval1 = setInterval(function() { x--; mainPlayer.set(x,1); },100);
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18255823/34397

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set` is a local variable that exists inside the `player()` function.

It has nothing to do with the returned object.

To add it to the object, write `this.set = function(...) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

As @musefan and @SLaks have said, `function set...` inside the `function player` are private (or scoped) to the `player` function.  To export them you can do what they have suggested:

```
this.set = function(setx, sety) {...}
```

Or, there is another way, which is to add the function to `player`'s prototype:

```
function player() {...}
player.prototype.set = function(setx, sety) {...}
```

This effectively adds a function to the `player`'s 'class' blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your functions are effectively 'private' to the `player` object. One option would be to define your functions like so:

```
this.set = function(setx, sety){
//...
}
```